# Killing a PHP process in Mac OS X

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, unix

I'm trying to kill a long running PHP process on the Mac (Lion), running a UAMP stack (zend server, unix/apache/mysql/php).

When I run the "top" command, I can't see a PHP process anywhere. I know it's hitting at least 100% CPU, because I can hear the fan, but I don't see anything with high CPU usage. I also can see the process logging things because I'm streaming the log file. On top of this, my browser is still waiting for the request.

UPDATE: Thanks for the hint about activity monitor. It appears that I had to look under ALL PROCESSES and found httpd running at 100%. Thanks again all.

Comment: What about apache's CPU usage?

Comment: stop the server, and the process will be dead too! First I saw you question I thought you were trying to kill pid using a sig via php script, if so read up this doc -> http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php

Comment: Quick tip: don't use top, use Activity Monitor (`/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app`). It provides better tools for sorting and categorizing processes, and most of the time it seem to generate _less_ processor load than `top`, somehow.

Comment: i don't see in top or in the activity monitor...

Comment: In most system the process name is "httpd"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a typical UAMP stack, PHP is running via `mod_php`, which doesn't start a separate PHP process. You'd need to kill the apache worker which is serving the request.

Comment: This is all I see, I don't see the apache process either PID   COMMAND      %CPU  TIME     #TH  #WQ  #POR #MREG RPRVT  RSHRD  RSIZE  VPRVT  VSIZE  PGRP PPID STATE    UID
7726  top          9.3   00:02.32 1/1  0    28   38    1488K  216K   2200K  19M    2379M  7726 7319 running  0
7724  launchd      0.0   00:00.00 2    0    52   45    380K   408K   816K   40M    2401M  7724 1    sleeping 1
7717- Google Chrom 0.0   00:03.58 5    1    96   268   45M    36M    67M    121M   811M   427  427  sleeping 501

Comment: @J K: try ps aux | grep apache or ps aux | grep php

Comment: In most system the process name is "httpd"